# Directory properties and subdirectories

Tags: cmake

The [CMake manual for `set_directory_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/command/set_directory_properties.html) claims:

> Set a property for the current directory and subdirectories.

To me this suggests that properties set in a parent directory should also be inherited to all subdirectories. But this does not seem to be the case. Consider:

**`CMakeLists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(foo CXX)

set_property(DIRECTORY . PROPERTY narf "zort")

add_subdirectory(a)

get_property(res DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY narf)
message("Property read from root: " ${res})
```

**`a/CMakeLists.txt`**

```
get_property(res DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY narf)
message("Property for a read from a: " ${res})
get_property(res DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY narf)
message("Property for root directory root read from a: " ${res})
```

This prints:

```
Property for a read from a: 
Property for root directory root read from a: zort
Property read from root: zort
```

So the property can only be retrieved from the directory on which it was set, not the subdirectories. The same is true when using the `set_directory_properties`/`get_directory_properties` to deal with the properties.

Did I misinterpret the respective section in the `set_directory_properties` manual? Or is it simply outdated/wrong?

Comment: If I look at CMake's source code this depends on a `chained` member of `cmPropertyDefinition` to be `true`. So I haven't checked if you can set this from the outside, but have you tried to call `define_property(DIRECTORY PROPERTY narf INHERITED BRIEF_DOCS "" FULL_DOCS"")`? Probably the `INHERITED` keyword does the trick (even if the `INHERITED` documentation says it's used for something else).

Comment: @Florian wow, you're right! I'd never have guessed that. The INHERITED documentation only refers to chaining scope types, not parent scopes of the same type. You should make this an answer, it is important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

If I look at CMake's source code this depends on the `chained` member of `cmPropertyDefinition` to be true.

So you can achieve this for your own directory property by using the `INHERITED` keyword with `define_property()`:

```
define_property(
    DIRECTORY 
    PROPERTY narf 
    INHERITED 
    BRIEF_DOCS "Brief Doc" 
    FULL_DOCS "Full Doc"
)
```

Even if the [`INHERITED` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/define_property.html) says only:

> If the `INHERITED` option then the `get_property()` command will chain up to the next higher scope when the requested property is not set in the scope given to the command. `DIRECTORY` scope chains to `GLOBAL`. `TARGET`, `SOURCE`, and `TEST` chain to `DIRECTORY`.

Comment: See the change [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/1879) which updates the docs to clarify the existing behavior. Hopefully it makes things a bit clearer.

Comment: I feel though while valuable, this does not really answers the question. The contradiction between the way set_directory_properties works and the way it is documented seem to remain.