# Abiding by CMake projects order in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

After generating VS2017 solution from CMake, projects are sorted in alphabetical order. I'd like them to be sorted by their call order in CMake project (this is the case in Xcode for instance). I unfortunately could'nt find how to this, if such a thing possible.

I tried renaming my libraries alphabetically in the order I want. But this is messy and doesn't solve the problem since I don't want to also rename third-party libraries. Any solution for this ?

Comment: That's a behavior of Visual Studio, not CMake. Have you considered using Project-Folders to group your project?

Comment: No I haven't, because it implies doing it over and over after each CMake solution re-generation. I know this is a VS behavior, but some of this behaviors can be controled during CMake generation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CMake: How do I change properties on subdirectory project targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092198/cmake-how-do-i-change-properties-on-subdirectory-project-targets) The folder structure can be defined in CMake.