# How to change the location of CMake's generated ALL_BUILD filter and Visual Studio's x64 directory?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

What I want to achieve:
A clean build directory generated by CMake for Visual Studio, with build system targets like ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK and additionally created directories like Visual Studio's x64 physically located somewhere else than in the root directory.

What I have tried:
As the accepted answer at [CMake: How do I change properties on subdirectory project targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092198/cmake-how-do-i-change-properties-on-subdirectory-project-targets) points out, all I have to do is activating the use of folders with the following line.

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS TRUE)
```

The problem:
This does only create a folder in the visual studio project structure for CMakePredefinedTargets, not in the physical filesystem. And the x64 directory keeps untouched too!

So what do I have to do?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. But if you are looking to separate your created binaries from the other generated files you can use the [`RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) property and related target properties to change their location.

Comment: So my messy build directory ... actually is quite common in CMake + Visual Studio?

Comment: More or less yes. I assume that you already have the build directory separate from your source tree. Usually the mess in the build-tree does not matter that much, because at least I am usually only interested in the .exe .dll .lib files. You can put these into another location as I described above. If you want to separate the desired build-results from all the other generated files, you can also consider adding install rules and then build the install target to copy all the important files out of your build-tree to a separate location.