# CMake per file optimizations

Tags: cmake

Elsewhere the question has been asked, "How do I turn off optimizations on one file?" The answer is usually something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.8 )

project( Hello )

add_executable( hello hello.c foo.c bar.c )

set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "" )

set_source_files_properties( hello.c 
                PROPERTIES
                COMPILE_FLAGS -O0 )
```

This works unless you invoke cmake like this:

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ../hello
```

And you get this in your `build.ninja`

```
FLAGS = -O3 -DNDEBUG   -O0
```

Checking the documentation on [COMPILE_FLAGS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_sf/COMPILE_FLAGS.html)

> Additional flags to be added when compiling this source file.

This makes sense, it is added to the list of COMPILE_FLAGS, it does not override existing compiler flags.

So, within CMake how can you override the optimisation level on a single file and being able to compile the rest of the project in `Release`? Otherwise you can force the compile to `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=""` which is the default behavior, but that somewhat defeats a selling point of Cmake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't overwrite compiler options with the `makefile` CMake generators on source file level. Options are always appended (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33834879/4763489) at [Is Cmake set variable recursive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828855/is-cmake-set-variable-recursive) for the complete formula).

This is - as far as I know - only supported with the `Visual Studio` solution/project generators. These generators have [flag tables](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmVS10CLFlagTable.h) to identify flags that are in the same group/that does overwrite a previous defined flag.

So yours is more like a feature request to also add compiler option tables to CMake's `makefile` generators.

---

**Alternatives**

I just wanted to add some crazy CMake magic I came up with as a workaround. Add the following to your main `CMakeLists.txt` after the `project()` command:

```perl
if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    define_property(
        SOURCE
        PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS 
        INHERITED 
        BRIEF_DOCS "brief-doc"
        FULL_DOCS  "full-doc"
    )
    string(TOUPPER ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} _build_type)
    set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${_build_type}}")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_${_build_type} "")
endif()
```

This example moves the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_<build type>` content into an new `COMPILE_FLAGS` directory property that is then linked to `COMPILE_FLAGS` source file property via [`define_property(... INHERITED ...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/define_property.html).

Now the build type specific flags are only defined in `COMPILE_FLAGS` for each source file and you can overwrite/change them e.g. with the code snippet from your example:

```
set_source_files_properties( 
    hello.c 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS -O0 
)
```

---

**References**

- [Directory properties and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885943/directory-properties-and-subdirectories)
- [CMake: How do I change properties on subdirectory project targets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45092198/cmake-how-do-i-change-properties-on-subdirectory-project-targets)

Comment: I've just forced CMake to Debug, hammered the options and then manually roll through the files and add flags. Negates a lot of the advantage of CMake...

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer The question would be why you need to remove the leading `-O3` option from the compiler's command line since: ["If you use multiple -O options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective."](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html).

Comment: It assumes gcc or gcc compatibility, which may apply to clang as well, but is is most certainly not something you can count on. For a large complex cross-platform project I think you need to handle this such that the flags are exactly what you desire. In a project I'm familiar with incorrect compilation would seriously harm functionality. It's a pity you can't override a single file.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer I added some CMake code that does accomplish what you have been asking for. But maybe better [to raise an issue at the CMake project](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues) to get "overwriting compiler flags on source level" implemented as a feature in future revisions.